# Flot Graph Tooltip with data other than a and y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a Flot graph with speed on y axis and distance on x axis and tooltip (x,y). I need to show another data "date" along with the x and y in tooltip only,not on the graph. What is the best way to do it.  The data in DB will be Speed|distance|date etc... So there is a relation between x,y and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create an array of dates that is indexed identical to your data point array.  In your tool tip function you can then query the date array by index to pull out the appropriate date for that point (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/wnJGx/1/)):

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
    $("#tooltip").remove();
    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
      randomDates[item.dataIndex].toDateString()); // query by data point index
  }
  else {
    $("#tooltip").remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..I have Zoom based on x selection after zooming item.dataIndex will work ???